# Sony PCM-M10 for ambient recording while WALKING

Tags: field-recording, sound, location, sony, pcm-m10

OK, so it's easy to do when you are not moving, but I need to walk and record ambient sound at the same time. (but not chew gum LOL)

Practical example: dual recording for video. Camera is mounted on handheld stabilizer Nebula, while is quiet but not completely silent. So IMHO no way to mount M10 anywhere near it.

One-man crew (I'm doing both camera and audio. Ta-da.)

So I'm thinking, perhaps:

- wear tight headphones (so they won't fall off) and mount M10 on top of the headphone band temple. Will look crazy but probably doable. Except it may still pick up the camera handling noise and operator breathing.
- instead of top of the band, make another headphone band that goes across behind my head, and mount the M10 there, with mics facing backwards. So the head would shield from the breathing and handling noises at the front, while M10 would still pick up the ambience.

Totally rubbish or is it doable? Or is there a better way?

Again, the factors here are:

- ensure one-man operation
- isolate from camera/operator's noise such as breathing, camera handling, stabilizer motors
- isolate from my steps vibration while walking (how?)
- isolate from wind (I hear great things about Rode DeadKitten, but I used to have it and threw it out as it shed like crazy! Doesn't really mix with video when you need to interchange lenses - last thing you want is some hair in the frame...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is have a couple of cheap (£20) tie-clip mics in a rucksack. If you use a bag with a top flap rather than a zip-up bag, you can clip each mic to either side of the flap, or attach them to the shoulder straps and have all the cables out of sight inside the bag.

I've done this for discreet recordings, and for walking around. With the top-flap, you can always clip the mics to the inside of the flap to protect from wind, if you don't find it affects sound quality too much.

Since the mics are on your back, you're avoiding things like breathing sounds, and you'll be getting more ambience and less of what's going on in front of you (like dialogue).

And also you won't be walking around with a microphone coming out of your head.

Comment: Well, the camera is there anyway, so it's not going to be THAT discreet :)

Comment: About the mics: so in your case (backpack straps) you wouldn't get any thumps when you were walking? I'm worried about it, thinking there must be proper suspension.

Comment: So I just tested a backpack version. Positioned M10 in a small neoprene camera bag, just enough size for tight fit. Bag has a flap that I secured to the backpack's strap. Two positions as follows. FRONT: getting my breathing,a s expected - but otherwise clear sound with no noise/thumping/rubbing. BACK (literally on teh strap taht goes over my back): no breathing, as a matter of fact speech is greatly attenuated; however I get a LOT of rubbing noise from the strap that I didn't hear with the front position. Interesting.

Comment: BTW tested with and without a foam windshield. Foam doesn't do jack sh*t protecting against the wind (I thought it'd have a little effect, but really virtually no difference!) Waiting on my Movo wind screen to test.

Comment: I'm listening back to a recording I did about a year ago walking through city streets with tie-clip mics in a bag. There aren't any 'thumps' as I'm walking along - maybe a tiny bit of rubbing against the bag, but I think it comes down to how carefully you fasten your bag and microphones.

You'll probably get more 'handling' noise from the onboard mics on the recorder as it's bulkier and therefore there's more to pick up handling noise.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mount an M10 to your head. You're going to get all kinds of sound transmission / handling noise (i.e. unusable audio). Put it in a shock-mount system akin to a [this rycote system](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=760271&gclid=Cj0KEQjwjrqvBRD6wf2fy-C61PIBEiQAUzKQTs_EDjX-CvHGWIgA8x1bQH7DW-ryIlYpLsNBaQSpkMIaApMM8P8HAQ&Q=&m=Y&is=REG&A=details) and use the windscreen. Yes, they shed, but if you brush them the loose hair will usually come out and then you're good. Yes it's expensive and will cost up front, but it will save you from having completely useless audio.

Basically, if you're looking for one-man operation it's the best you're going to get. But you will still have to mind your breathing and walk softly. Not because the vibration will carry from your footsteps, but because your footsteps will be all over your recordings.